# ECS CloudFormation stack always shows CREATE_PROGRESS

Tags: python, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm creating ECS cluster using CF stack. I used the same template with some modification:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ecs.html

I have sample docker image(simple python file, no web app) on AWS registry
and in a template, I customized task definition and service like this

```
 "service":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::Service",
      "Properties":{
        "Cluster":{
          "Ref":"ECSCluster"
        },
        "DesiredCount":"1",
        "TaskDefinition":{
          "Ref":"taskdefinition"
        }
      }
    },
    "taskdefinition":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties":{
        "Family":{
          "Fn::Join":[
            "",
            [
              {
                "Ref":"AWS::StackName"
              },
              "testing"
            ]
          ]
        },
        "ContainerDefinitions":[
          {
            "Name":"my-sample",
            "Cpu":"10",
            "Essential":"true",
            "Image":"842352615873.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-sample:test",
            "Memory":200,
          }],
        }
    },
```

After making this modification to the cf template the stack always shows status 'in progress' although ec2 instance is attached to cluster.
When I ssh on the instance and check docker images then my image is not there (as opposed to busybox) and docker ps -a doesn't show the container. I think error may be in task definition or service that I just created. Please help

Comment: Is the instance properly attached to the cluster? Does the stack create successfully? If you view the service in the AWS console and click on the events tab, what does it say? Was the `my-sample` image built with a `CMD` line?

Comment: Instance is properly attached to cluster but the problem is that stack showing status in progress. If I see stack's event it shows that service is in progress. I just changed the task definition and service resource and I think, some mistake I'm making here that I really don't understand

Comment: Sounds like your container is having an issue running. If you look at stopped tasks, there should be more info on why the attempts to run the container have been failing. Make sure your EC2 instance has the proper IAM instance profile to be able to fetch images from ECR.

Comment: @manzoor Hi, Manzoor, I changed the title a bit to highlight your problem, I hope this is OK with you.

Comment: @jordanm Permission with ECR might be one problem with container registry for above mentioned case But for testing I changed Image with "library/helloworld" instead of registry url, although it creates the image and I can check container via ssh but the problem is that the stack status is still showing 'in progress' so problematic section is basically 'service' in resources and in event's I can see 'service is in progress as always'.

Comment: @manzoor stack creation/update doesn't finish until the service "stabilizes".

Comment: @manzoor I think the best way would be to make DesiredCount as 0 in the CF template and then run it.. If it completes which it should, try making the desired count as 1 manually after that.. even if then it has issues, I would say run other steps manually as well, i.e. download the image manually and then set desired count as 1... this would help in knowing which part is the problem... At this moment it is definitely looking like image is not getting downloaded and that is the problem.. try doing it manually to confirm.. maybe some instance role ? internet access issue?

Comment: Set your service DesiredCount to zero, create/update your ECR, load your image(s), then set your service DesiredCount > 0.